# How to update date-time of system on application start-up from the internet?

Tags: c#, datetime, date, time

My C# application is dependent on system date and time and i want to check the date-time of the system on application start-up from internet. But i don't know how to do it?

Comment: Guess you can reuse some 3rd party SNTP libraries. Googled??

Comment: what do you want, it a bit unclear: the dateTime of the system or the dateTime of the internet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Best way to retrieve accurate date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682350/c-sharp-best-way-to-retrieve-accurate-date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Query an NTP Server from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c-sharp)

Comment: i want to update the date-time of the system from the internet automatically in application start-up.

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe it's not so simple.

If you absolutely have synchronize system's time take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowsSystemTime_Syncher.aspx). It involves calling windows system api and I'm pretty sure you'll need high privileges to run that code.

If you just need to get time from the internet for your application [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c-sharp) has the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried lot of solution's but the one below worked for me .

```
Process.Start("time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

just use Process Class and CMD to change the Time ,and i think you will need Administrator Privilege for that .

You can use this [class](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#GawBxmf1je8/NTP/NtpClient.cs&q=ntp%20lang%3ac#&l=34) to get the time from an NTP Server .

Comment: but it seems that this instruction won't change the date time in anyway ? it replaces system date time with itself

Comment: @geogeek and where is the difference ?