# How do I request server time using ASP.Net/ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm creating a countdown timer for a project I'm on and I feel its important to get the most accurate time possible. What is more accurate and, more importantly, the most unalterable than server time?

The project requires days/hours/minutes/seconds so if I could grab the exact time the page was requested from the server I could then just throw it in a JavaScript variable and work it out from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is run on the server, it gives you the server time.

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

This you can put in a hidden field on the page and read it with JS when the page loads.

Then, you'll either

- need to also know the client time the page loaded so you can calculate how much time has elapsed

  **OR**
- have JS increment a counter value that you add to the server time.

With either of these, of course, you're using `setTimeout` to kick off some JS function.

---

However, **don't forget about time zones!!!** Is this important?

Comment: OP, wants use server time in javascript, every one knows DateTime.Now exists.

Comment: @Saeed, okay, so put `DateTime.Now` in a hidden field and read it with JS and then start the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the timespan of the difference between the objetive time and current time and then total seconds:

```
TimeSpan diff = objetiveDateTime - DateTime.Now;
int totalSeconds = diff.TotalSeconds();
```

Some other way would be to get the objetive date and save it in a js variable in some format js understands (e.g. "October 13, 1975 11:13:00") and then create `Date` object in js.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you query a NIST time server?  You must consider which stratum your server is on before you assume that the server is a better source than the client.  Also consider that you are posting back to a web server, not the DC, which is more often the reference time source for a network.  Lastly, if you do not have an authoritative time source to query, consider allowing the user to put in a time hack, or a manual input that would be the difference between your time and the authoritative time.

[How to Query an NTP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c)

[A jQuery countdown clock that I have had success with.](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)