# Update system time and date from internet

Tags: c#, windows, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Query an NTP Server from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c)

I try send email with my program but if time and date not set, sending is be fail.

How to update system time and date from internet in C#?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c/1193997#1193997) show you how to retrieve the time from a time server.

Are you sure you want to update the system time? Maybe it is sufficient to use the retrieved time in the email.