# .Net API to get exact time for Internet Time Server

Tags: c#, ntp

I need to know if there is any .NET API exists to fetch the current time from Internet Time Server, so that changing the system time at the client will not affect the integrity of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a third party library that should bail you out.  See the [NtpClient class](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#GawBxmf1je8/NTP/NtpClient.cs&q=ntp%20lang:c#&l=34)

For other alternatives, see the similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c)

Answer (score 4):

you have several options - though none built-in:

- http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client-SID571.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ntpclient.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/SNTPClient.aspx
- http://www.rebex.net/time.net/ (commercial)

Answer (score 1):

Ah - no. Simple like that. No NTP support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party [NTPClient.cs](https://github.com/nothingmn/robchartier-classlibrary/blob/master/robchartier-classlibrary/Network/NTPClient.cs).

Example how to use:

```
DateTime time_nist_gov = NTPClient.GetTime().TransmitTimestamp; // uses NTPClient.DefaultTimeServer = "time.nist.gov"
DateTime time_windows_com = NTPClient.GetTime("time.windows.com").TransmitTimestamp;
DateTime pool_ntp_org = NTPClient.GetTime("pool.ntp.org").TransmitTimestamp;
```