# Setting your own Date and Time in vbNET without relying to your PC's time and date

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, time

I want to set my own date and time in my vbNet app so I wont rely to my PC's date&time.
Is it possible to have your own date and time in vbNET running even if its closed and when the next time you open it, it still display the real time and date?
How can I do that? any sample codes?

Comment: No, that's not possible.  If your app isn't running, you have no choice but to depend on the system clock.

Comment: @MattJohnson, oh sad. Anyway, thankyou sir. :)

Comment: Not unless you explicitly retrieved the time from an external source on the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to keep track of your own time when the application is closed without relying on the system time (you'd need to know how long your application was closed for, and you could only use the system time for that).

However, if you really wanted to, you could fetch the current time from an [NTP Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) each time you need to know what the time is.

There are questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204987/net-api-to-get-exact-time-for-internet-time-server) asking how to do that.