# Update PC time with server - C#

Tags: c#, date, time

Does anyone know how I would force the computer to update the time with the time server, you can do this manually doing: Right Click on time -> Adjust date/time -> Internet Time -> Change Settings -> and update now.

I want to write a program that incorpates that same functionality, but does it automaticly.

Any suggestions?

Darestium

Comment: You do realize Windows already does this, right?  It automagically synchronizes like once a week.

Comment: Check [NtpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Though I dont know why you need it, We have something similar but we actually simulate a date on client using remoting/wcf which sync with server as our rest of communication is using Remoting/WCF. Changing time on client blindly may cause some other issues with other applications running on the client box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write directly in the windows registry from your program, the interested key is :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters
```

Reference [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223184) .

To learn how to read, write into the windows registry from your C# applications, take a look at [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx) .