# Using VB.NET to query NTP Servers

Tags: vb.net, time, ntp

As the title describes I am looking for a way to query for the UTC time from NTP/SNTP Servers from 'VB.NET'. The only libraries I have found for VB.NET to such tasks appear require a fairly large sum of different forms of currency.

Any suggestions, comments, methods, or links?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Query an NTP Server from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to Query an NTP Server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-from-c-sharp) .  Not marking as a duplicate, as the solution linked to is in C#, and you asked for VB.NET.  However, this can be compiled into a library, and still used within a VB.NET project - since everything compiles to MSIL anyway.

Otherwise, as shown in the linked examples, the implementations for NTP/SNTP are simple enough that implementations could easily be re-created from spec in VB.net with hopefully reasonable amounts of code.

Comment: I noticed that exact link you provided but I didn't have the courage nor assurance it could be compiled into a simple library due to lack of familiarity. I went ahead and proceeded to complete success. Thanks!

Comment: @zach: You don't have to compile it into a library. You can just translate the code to VB.NET. It's trivial if you spend a little time, and even easier if you use an [automated translator](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).