# How can i get the correct date if system date is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using
 `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`
 to get the current date. If i change the system date the date returned by DateTime.Now() also changes which is vulnerable.

Any one has a solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this; consider being on a plane without a WiFi connection, how would you get the time except from the local machine? With "vulnerable", do you mean that you're basing security on the client time?

Comment: Sorry i would like to point out that am connected to network.

Comment: Still, is it for security purposes you need the time or for user convenience (ie in case they set their clock wrong)?

Comment: Its for user convenience

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a NTP server to retrieve the current date/time in that case.
Look at an implementation posted in another question.
[How to Query an NTP Server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

When you don't trust the time of the machine you can use an NTP (Network Time Protocol) client call to ask a trusted time server for the correct time.

There are many client codes. For example http://www.dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client-SID571.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hai all thanks for the comments and gateways.

I would like to share one link which helped me.

http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/c-get-nist-internet-time/

Comment: You should summarize the content of that link, and how it applies to your question. Link only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: The same code has been used. So that i can access the actual date