# Autoit UDP Request To NTP Timeserver

Tags: autoit

I need to use autoit to get the time from a local ntp timeserver.

```
; Function gets time from timeserver to not relay on pc time
Func get_Time_From_Time_Server() 
    Local $iSocket = UDPOpen(TCPNameToIP($s_Time_Server),  123) ; Port 123
    Local $data = ""

    While $data = ""
        $data = UDPRecv($iSocket, 100)
        Sleep(100)
    Wend        
EndFunc
```

Opening the `UDP` connection seems to work, but `$data` stays equal to `""`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is any request to socket in your code?

Here is example of receiving data from local ntp ([Source](https://autoit-script.ru/index.php?topic=5920.0)):

```
#include <Date.au3>

$recv = NTP_Connect("10.24.1.20")
ConsoleWrite($recv & @CRLF)
Parse_Time($recv)

Func NTP_Connect($NTP_Server)
    UDPStartup()
    Dim $socket = UDPOpen(TCPNameToIP($NTP_Server), 123)
    $status = UDPSend($socket, MakePacket("1b0e01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"))
    $data = ""
    While $data = ""
        $data = UDPRecv($socket, 100)
        Sleep(100)
    WEnd
    UDPCloseSocket($socket)
    UDPShutdown()
    Return $data
EndFunc   ;==>NTP_Connect

Func MakePacket($d)
    Local $p = ""
    While $d
        $p &= Chr(Dec(StringLeft($d, 2)))
        $d = StringTrimLeft($d, 2)
    WEnd
    Return $p
EndFunc   ;==>MakePacket

Func Parse_Time($bdata)
    $unsignedHexValue = StringMid($bdata, 83, 8)
    $value = UnsignedHexToDec($unsignedHexValue)
    $TZinfo = _Date_Time_GetTimeZoneInformation()
    $UTC = _DateAdd("s", $value, "1900/01/01 00:00:00")
    ConsoleWrite($UTC & @CRLF)
    If $TZinfo[0] <> 2 Then ; 0 = Daylight Savings not used in current time zone / 1 = Standard Time
        $TZoffset = ($TZinfo[1]) * - 1
    Else ; 2 = Daylight Savings Time
        $TZoffset = ($TZinfo[1] + $TZinfo[7]) * - 1
    EndIf
    $UTC = _DateAdd("n", $TZoffset, $UTC)
    $m = StringMid($UTC, 6, 2)
    $d = StringMid($UTC, 9, 2)
    $y = StringMid($UTC, 1, 4)
    $h = StringMid($UTC, 12, 2)
    $mi = StringMid($UTC, 15, 2)
    $s = StringMid($UTC, 18, 2)
EndFunc

Func UnsignedHexToDec($n)
    $ones = StringRight($n, 1)
    $n = StringTrimRight($n, 1)
    Return Dec($n) * 16 + Dec($ones)
EndFunc   ;==>UnsignedHexToDec
```

Explanation of request packet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171366/ntp-request-packet).