# Get Internet Time instead of pc time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, real-time

I have an application that runs on local machines (multiple users) most likely its like a DTR system. This application is based on client-server architecture, so in this I need the same time over all the PCs, so by any method when on any PC application starts it fetch the current time from internet or from any server which provide accurate and same time to all the users. I searched other solutions but its no luck.

Any ideas and alternatives is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can query an NTP server. This is basically a server that offers information about the current time. There are servers like pool.ntp.org or google time servers under time1.google.com and so on.

In order to query these you can refer to previous answers with complete code like this on:

[How to Query an NTP Server using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c)

It's in C# but you can easily convert it to VB.net with tools like http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx