# How to find the difference between current local time and system time

Tags: c#

I want to find the difference between the current local time and system time  (consider system's time is 5 min ahead of actual local time).

I am fetching data from a server machine(located at PST timezone) and in my project, time is important factor and the code will be deployed on a server machine (PST).
Now my problem is that the server's time is 5 minutes ahead of the actual PST Time. I want to get that difference programatically.

Comment: How is the time "5 min ahead"? That doesn't sound like a TZ issue.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up an NTP client, Windows has one built in.

Comment: Take a look at this discussion, maybe it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c

Comment: @Brunis probably he hasn't the rights to change the time?

Comment: What format are you fetching the time in?

Comment: My next question is where is his effort at attempting to calculate the TZ difference? We don't even know the language he is using? This lacks effort.

Comment: I am fetching and saving time in UTC format and i doesn't have permission to change time

Comment: thanx to all for valuable reply