# How to get real current date in c#?

Tags: c#, date, system

I want to get the real current date in C#. Currently I am facing an issue that if someone changes the system time, it will show wrong time and date. I used `DateTime.Now`. But it's not working in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use NTP-Server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c

Answer (score 5):

Get it from [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm)

```
var client = new TcpClient("time.nist.gov", 13);
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
{
    var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var utcDateTimeString = response.Substring(7, 17);
    var localDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(utcDateTimeString, "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
}
```

And make sure port 13 is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

[`DateTime.Now`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx) is returning the time as expected: that's dictated by the system.

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time.

If you want to rely on "real time", you'll need to go on further and reconcile with something like one of the [NIST](http://www.nist.gov/pml/div688/grp40/its.cfm) [time servers](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) - this way you can match, and inform of inconsistencies or whatever you need to do that relies on time in the real world and not as stated by a human-editable time on a single machine.