# How to get Parse Server DateTime?

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a method in Parse that would let me get the current time that is running on the server? I need to fetch the time from the server, and not depend on the local device's clock.

I'm using C#, Unity SDK. TIA!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c

Answer (score 6):

You can create a cloud function, written in javascript, which will get the date and return it.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getServerTime", function(request, response) {
    var dateToday = new Date();
    response.success(dateToday.toDateString());
});
```

You will likely want to do some specific formatting of the response so you can sensibly parse it on the client.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet? I've never tried Parse Cloud Code before.