# How to get Parse Server Time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Is there a method in Parse SDK (Swift) that would let me get the current time that is running on the server? I need to fetch the time from the server, and not depend on the local device's clock.

Comment: You need to expose an API in your server and use that API in your client code. the api can simply return a string of the current time then use:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter

Comment: You can create a cloud function to get the server time take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724499/how-to-get-parse-server-datetime