# Device date time - Xamarin application

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I'm using DateTime to get device date and time information but I need to ensure device date/time is synchronized with network date/time, and if not, tell user to sync it before use the app. How can I do that for android and ios?

Is there any kind of device enviroment property where I can obtain that info or should I have to compare it to a server date/time with same timezone?

Comment: you would need to query a time server - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c

Comment: thanks, @Jason. Answer and I will mark as correct

Comment: @ÉderRocha: better upvote the duplicate I guess..... if it is a duplicate....