# HttpWebRequest - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, winforms, ssl, visual-studio-2015, httpwebrequest

I want to try get current DateTime like this :

```
try {
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.timestampconvert.com/");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36";
    req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    req.Referer = string.Empty;
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.Timeout = 25000;

    //req.Proxy = proxy;
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse();

    Stream Stream = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
    string reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(reader_str);

    var divs = from div in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    select div;

    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

    foreach(var div in divs) {
        if (div.Attributes["class"] != null) {
            if (div.Attributes["class"].Value == "remarkrow") {
                if (div.InnerText.Contains("Computation based on input date")) {
                    CultureInfo cultureinfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    dt = Convert.ToDateTime(div.InnerText.Replace("\n\t*)Computation based on input date ", string.Empty), cultureinfo);
                    dt = dt.AddHours(2).AddMinutes(30);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    DateTime dt_ = dt;
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

But it has an exception like below :

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

How can i fix this error?

Comment: That page doesn't even provide the current date. It's a time converter. I'm sure there must be other pages / APIs which would give you the time directly, maybe in a JSON object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: How can i disable SSL/TLS certificate check in codes?
Would you please introduce me a free api to get current datetime!
I was using that site for several years - because it was so light & fast.

Comment: Add following to beginning of your code (after the request) :ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Surely they'd want that *before* the request...?

Comment: The server setup is broken. It is not providing the full certificate chain but only the leaf certificate. See [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.timestampconvert.com) and look for *"Chain issues - incomplete"*. And no, this can not be fixed by enforcing TLS 1.2 as suggested.

Comment: By adding this code : `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` at the beginning exception vanished. But what is this code exactly & what do it do?

Comment: It sets the TLS version

Comment: I do n't want that code affect on all of my codes! i want to change SecurityProtocol  of that request only, not other requests.

Comment: Why do you think it would affect anything other than this request?

Comment: free api to get current datetime - how about from an NTP server instead of this awful "scrape some html off a server that puts the time in a webpage" way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c

Comment: NTP server > All those codes have deprecated & do n't work any more.http://time.windows.com = Not Found | pool.ntp.org = needs user name & password

Comment: That's because you're trying to use them via HTTP instead of NTP. Read the link that Caius Jard gave you, it shows how to do it properly