# What is the best way to synchronize clocks via C# when UDP Sockets (NTP) are not available?

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, websocket, ntp

I am working on a C# game in Unity with a WebAssembly build target, thus I do not have access to `System.Net.Sockets` and [the standard approach to clock synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193955/how-to-query-an-ntp-server-using-c) (i.e., UDP connection to a NTP server like `pool.ntp.org`).

I can use WebSockets, so [an approach like this seems reasonable](https://github.com/shogo82148/go-webntp). However, I'd prefer the backend be implemented in C# instead of running a side-car.

More importantly, I need the results to be accurate within a few milliseconds (and I'm not sure this will be).

Are there any canonical clock synchronization approaches in C# without UDP sockets?